# Local Windows Jenkins Proxy connection issue

Tags: jenkins, windows-10, port

I have installed a local Jenkins in my Windows 10 machine.

I have created admin password, and I am not aware of the proxy to set for my local machine. Kindly suggest what value should I provide in **"Server" and "Port"** (I hope default port 8080 should be given) under HTTP Proxy Configuration. And should I provide Jenkins credentials or my machine credentials?

I have tried providing Server as "localhost", but its not connecting. kindly provide inputs. Thanks!

Comment: Normally you don't need to touch proxy settings of Jenkins, unless the machine you are running Jenkins on needs a proxy to connect to the internet. Then you need to copy the proxy settings to Jenkins for it to be able to download updates and plugins.

Comment: If I did not give any proxy, under Available section of Manage plugins I am facing issue as "There were errors checking the update sites: SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out". Kindly help.

Comment: Search in your Windows settings for "proxy". If proxy is enabled, copy server name and port to Jenkins.

Comment: Manual proxy setup is not done in my windows settings. Not sure how to proceed. Now I am facing "There were errors checking the update sites: UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io" under Available section of Manage plugins.

Comment: Without proxy if i give TestURL as "https://www.ggogle.com" then I am getting the issue as "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"